# Ubuntu 21.04 freeze with display port

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, displayport

When i connect my monitor with display port, ubuntu freeze. Hard reboot not help because system not starting.
But, when i connect with HDMI, it's all OK.

- 5.11.0-22-generic - ubuntu version
- GeForce 1660 OSX - Driver Version: 460.84

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert on video cards, but I often had problems with with video cards under Linux and almost always similar problems were solved by "[Draining the Capacitors](https://fosscoder.blogspot.com/2015/06/dont-ever-forget-to-drain-capacitors.html)"   Maybe try a more powerful power supply?